# convertPoint to window coordinates doesn't work as I expect

Tags: uiview, uilabel, subview, cgpoint

I need to know the absolute position  of my UILabel in the window coordinates.
This UILabel (in the code below, uil) is located inside a view at 34 x 174 y of the view coordinate system)

I see that many psay that  convertPoint should be used to get the absolute values.
But after convertion I get a CGPoint that is still at 34 x 174 y.
While I expected coordinates referring to the screen window.

Could you explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to get the window coordinates of my label?

```
CGPoint cgp = [uil convertPoint:uil.frame.origin fromView:nil];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `convertPoint:toView:` says, "If view is nil, this method instead converts to window base coordinates."  It sounds like you want that rather than `fromView:`.

Comment: Yes thanks. This is what I want but unfortunately the CGPoint even with CGPoint cgp = [uil convertPoint:uil.frame.origin toView:nil]; remains at he same coordinates (34 x 174 y)

Comment: That's unexpected.  What do you get if you use `NSLog(@"Super: %@", [uil superview]);` at the point where you do the conversion?

Comment: Hello thanks for help. I solved instead of writin toView:nil I used toView:uiv.superview where uiv is the view containing the label.